# Custom sort objects in an array in swift

Tags: arrays, sorting, object, types, swift2

Needed to sort Objects (Class/Datatype), Alphabetically.

UnSorted Array::

```
[main.Apple, main.Zoo, main.IceCream, main.Apple, main.IceCream]
```

Sorted Array:: Alphabetically Type @ the Front

```
[main.Apple, main.Apple, main.IceCream, main.IceCream, main.Zoo]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the solutions that I have found till now:

1. Make use of `sortInPlace` function and `dynamicType` to check for class names e.g.:- `String(firstDataType.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!` this retrieves the class name for the Object.

   ```
   unsortedArray.sortInPlace({(firstDataType,secondDataType) in
   return String(firstDataType.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
       .localizedStandardCompare(String(secondDataType.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
   ```

   })

   [Demo Link](http://swiftstub.com/675584947/?v=beta)